# mPDF not showing image in generated PDF instead showing red x symbol and full url for background image

Tags: php, pdf, symfony1, symfony-1.4, mpdf

Recently I have moved from my staging server to production server and I don't have access to any of these servers.
Both of these servers are linux.

On the new server while generating the pdf using mPDF with symfony 1.4 framework, images like rupee symbol are not getting displayed instead a small red "x" symbol is getting displayed in pdf.

Also, when I try to give background image to pdf, full image path like "http://example.com/image/rupee-image.jpg" is getting displayed instead of image.

Rupee symbol, other images and background images are working fine on my staging server.

When, I did $mpdf->showImageError(), It's saying "mPDF Image Error:  Could not find image file" and pasting the url in browser displays the image perfectly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to put relative path also, but no luck.

Answer (score 4):

mPDF is telling you that it's not finding the image.

Without seeing your code it's difficult to hint you on what's wrong.

Still you probably what to try referring to your images using a full path locally.

So instead of reference like http://example.com/image/rupee-image.jpg

use something like */var/www/mysite/image/rupee-image.jpg* , same as if checking the image is there using the command line.

HTH

Comment: Its worked for me, I have tried many tricks but If I apply the relative path of image while creating PDF its works fine. thank you so much @rtome

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, i fixed it with replacing http:// to https://. Watch out for it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself... I have created a variable in my template and then replaced that variable with image location from my action class, using $mpdf->WriteHTML(str_replace('rupee_symbol','₹',$html1));

Answer (score 0):

My problem was PHP 7 in this case! I check condition

```
if (!empty('/images/someimg.png')) {
    echo '<img ...';
} else {
    echo 'error in PHP 7';
}
```

Be carefull using it. Version PHP 7.0.19